# Service chaining in wso2 esb return illegal character

Tags: json, rest, api, wso2, messageformat

I have service chaining in wso2 REST to REST. 
Here is the scenario :

1. First REST API (GET) just produce simple json
2. Second REST API (PUT) consume the first rest api result, and produce it as json.

To achieve that i make some component in wso2 :

1. REST API

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <api context="/flight" name="Flight" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <resource methods="PUT" uri-template="/">
   <inSequence>
       <property expression="//airport_cd/text()" name="airport_cd"
           scope="default" type="STRING" />
       <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
           value="GET" />

       <send receive="insertFlightSeq">
           <endpoint>
               <address format="rest"
                   uri="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" />
           </endpoint>
       </send>
       <send />
   </inSequence>
   <outSequence>
       <send />
   </outSequence>
   <faultSequence />
   ```
2. Sequence to aceess the second rest API (insertFlightSeq)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <sequence name="insertFlightSeq" trace="disable"xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <payloadFactory media-type="json">
   <format>
       {"hello":"hello"}
   </format>
   <args>
       <arg evaluator="json" expression="$."/>
   </args>
   </payloadFactory>

   <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="PUT"/>
   <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
   <send receive="sendFlightSeq">
       <endpoint>
           <address format="rest" uri="http://localhost:8084/AeroData/flight/"/>
       </endpoint>
   </send>
   </sequence>
   ```
3. Another sequence to output it

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <sequence name="sendFlightSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <send/>
   </sequence>
   ```

But in wso2 log console it shows illegal character and the second API cant accept that character.

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Illegal character
((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is
allowed between tokens
```

This is the wso2 console log. 
It's shows like `[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xab]V[0xca]H[0xcd][0xc9][0xc9]W[0xb2][0x82][0xd2][0xb5][0x0][0x92]H[0x81];[0x11][0x0][0x0][0x0][\r][\n]`

[image]

Is this happen because of messager formatter like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281426/wso2-esb-unexpected-character-error-when-submitting-json-to-proxy-service/34302776) ?

Comment: Your configuration looks good. Did you remove or change `application/json` formatter in `axis2.xml` by any chance?

Comment: @Bhathiya no i didn't change that

Comment: Did anyone have a solution for this? I am also struggling with same use-case and getting the same errors.